# Getting "Object are not valid as a React child" when mapping API response

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this in **App.js**:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { data: 'false' };
  this._getData = this._getData.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  this._getData();
}

_getData = () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:8888/chats';

  fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ chats: json.chats }))
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
         // console.log(this.props);
         this.state.chats &&
         this.state.chats.map((item, key) =>
           <div key={key}>
             {item}
           </div>
         )
      }
      <Chat chats={this.state.chats} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is the response from **http://localhost:8888/chats**:

```
{"chats":[{"buddy":"x","lastMessage":"Hey how are you?","timestamp":"2017-12-01T14:00:00.000Z"},{"buddy":"y","lastMessage":"I agree","timestamp":"2017-12-03T01:10:00.000Z"}]}
```

Aand I am getting this:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {buddy, lastMessage, timestamp}). If you meant to render a collection
>   of children, use an array instead.

```
in div (at App.js:40) // <div key={key}>
in div (at App.js:35) // <div className="App">
in App (at index.js:6) // ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

and it is poinig at this line

```
.then(json => this.setState({ chats: json.chats }))
```

What am I doing wrong ? I read some one saying this

> Don't pass an object as a prop to React.child. Instead, pass it as {...item} and then access using props.{property} that might fix your problem

But I'm not sure how to implement!

Comment: Each element of the array is an *object*. If you want to render the message, do `{item.lastMessage}`

Comment: @Li357 I am a new with React. Can you please explain where exactly I need to make the chage ? Thanks

Comment: @Li357 and what if I wanted to pass other items as well such as `buddy` and `timestamp` ?

Comment: Then render multiple elements.

Comment: @Li357 I am still now sure where to do the `{item.lastMessage}`. Do u mean having something like this `<Chat chats={this.state.chats.lastMessage} />}` ? If so, then that is not working

Comment: In your `div` inside `map`.

Comment: @Li357 I got what u mean. It is working. Thanks sooo much.

Comment: @Li357 if u want post it as an anwer so that maybe other might benefit form it as well and both of us going to get some points :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you're mapping:

```
this.state.chats.map((item, key) =>
  <div key={key}>
    {item}
  </div>
)
```

If you look at the response from the server, `item` here is actually an *object* like this:

```
{
  "buddy": "x",
  "lastMessage": "Hey how are you?",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-01T14:00:00.000Z"
}
```

And in React, you can't render an object as a direct child of an element, `div` in this case. You have to render *a specific property of the object*:

```
<div>
  {item.lastMessage}
</div>
```

And if you have multiple things:

```
<div>
  <div>{item.lastMessage}</div>
  <div>{item.buddy}</div>
  …
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to render all of the objects instead of just a specific property of the object?

Answer (score 1):

Your `json.chats` is an array of objects. You are trying to iterate over each one and render them. As the error states, you can't do that. You have to process the object more in order for the elements to render.

`json.chats = [{"buddy":"x","lastMessage":"Hey how are you?","timestamp":"2017-12-01T14:00:00.000Z"},{"buddy":"y","lastMessage":"I agree","timestamp":"2017-12-03T01:10:00.000Z"}]`

I imagine you are only using `buddy` and `lastMessage`. The following would render what you're looking for. Notice that I'm extracting values out of your object and only rendering the values, which are strings.

```
const chats = json.chats.map(json => {
  return (
    <div>
      {json.buddy}: {json.lastMessage}
    </div>
  )
})
```